# Changing hiding div after after textbox change

Tags: jquery

I m using jquery to submit my form. Please tell me how do i hide a div containing error message after someone has typed something in the textbox

```
$('#resourcename').onchange(function() {
    $('.resouecetitle').hide();
}
```

```html
<div class="resouecetitle" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom :5px;  color:#F00; font-size:11px;">Enter the name of the Resource</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method to achieve what you want as following code :

```
$('#resourcename').on('keyup',function() { //<-- textbox id name
   $('.resouecetitle').hide(); //<-- error message container
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you pleases do little bit changes in your code as bellow.

```
HTML :   
   //here i put one demo textbox with id.which will be change with your textbox.
   <input type="text" id="resourcename" name="test">

   <div class="resouecetitle" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom :5px;  color:#F00; font-size:11px;">Enter the name of the Resource</div>

Jquery :

   $('#resourcename').on('keypress',function(e) { 
       $('.resouecetitle').hide();
   });
```

I hope this will help you.